# Low-quality posts review queue shows answers from deleted questions

Tags: support, review, deleted-questions, low-quality-posts, specific-answer

I just [reviewed an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4084217) to a deleted question in Low Quality Posts review queue. Below the question, I can see only

> ## Question
>
> *question not found*

and the [link in the right column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145052/what-is-a-good-default-font-family-for-any-ie8-9-chrome-firefox/8145067#8145067) leads me to a page saying that the question was deleted. Only in the Low Quality Posts review queue history I can see that the question was titled *What is a good default font family for any IE8/9, Chrome & Firefox?*.

During writing this question, the answer changed to

> ## Answer
>
> answer not found

too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very rare edge-case. The question's migration had been rejected. Since the question was already deleted, it did not get undeleted. However, the rejection cause all its answers to be undeleted (at least temporarily), resulting in a bunch of non-deleted answers on a deleted question. Any low quality posts in there got added to review.

The answers have now all been automatically deleted again, as they should be.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! This is really amusing coincidence. I believe it would be fixed sometime, but it is a low-priority issue.